# Mac Terminal or iTerm: Copy the current command (not including prompt)?

Tags: bash, mac, terminal, clipboard, iterm2

I am using Terminal or iTerm (iTerm2). Let's say I've typed in a command but haven't hit enter yet. Or maybe I used the up arrow to navigate through my command history. How do I copy the current command to the MacOS clipboard? But I also don't want it to include the prompt. Is there a keyboard short cut to do this?

For example, let's say the terminal is showing this:

```
myhostname:Documents kevuser$ mkdir cool_directory_name
```

What is the keyboard shortcut to copy `mkdir cool_directory_name` to the Mac OS clipboard?

Comment: AOK to ask here, but http://askdifferent.com may be a quicker place to find an answer.. Just cruise on over there and search for an answer, you may be pleasantly surprised.